# Screen auto lock on iPhone does not work

Tags: iphone, ios

My 2 week old iPhone 8 won’t lock automatically after the set limit of 30 seconds. My phone remains unlocked until I physically press the lock screen button.

Even then, if the screen is touched, the display wont turn off itself.

**How can I get my autolock screen function to work?**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) It'd be good if you could [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/303662/edit) your question to, well, include a question. It's not clear what you're asking of us?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my iphone 8 and this morning kept googling answers thinking it was a major problem.  Then I have restarted the phone and it now works.  Should have done this first! lol

Comment: To the person who voted that down what a dick